# chinese font in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts

I have a site with some swf file.
I have to translate all site in chinese, and when I have opened my flash project copy into a textfield (with font trebuchet) the text in chinese.
I have compiled and seen into many computers: Windows7 Windows Xp and Mac.
I'm very surprised because I seen the chinese character correctly but I have only copy the text I don't include any characters or font. Is possible this? For me is very simple now but I don't want that in a pc I don't see character because I have to include chinese font. But now is working and I see correctly. Why this? Is corret to don't include chinese font?

Comment: I believe if a font is present on the system that matches the locale for the unicode characters then they can be displayed.  I believe also if you wanted to guarantee consistency you'd still want to embed a font for these fields, but through testing and/or research you may find most systems you need to support already have a chinese font available (I've never had to deal with locales myself but understand some things about fonts).

Comment: I have tried with a new system without install any characters and I seen well all site.. I'm very surprised.. for now I don't embed into flash I hope that isn't a problem

Comment: Flash will automatically embed the characters contained in text fields added through the authoring tool. You only need to embed a font manually when you have dynamic text (user input or script-generated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like most modern systems will have support:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_fonts

You'd lose in filesize by embedding a font but gain some extra control on the font smoothing and ability to rotate the font, but it looks like you'd be safe not embedding assuming you're targeting mostly customers that have moved up to or beyond XP service pack 3.